# adding a node to a collection using JUNG2

Tags: collections, jung

I am trying  to add a node like this `( C.add(n)))`

I have this problem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Unknown Source))

Non-executable code example:

```java
UndirectedSparseMultigraph<MyNode, MyLink> g = getgraph1();
Collection<MyNode> c = null ;
for( MyNode n : g.getVertices() ){
  if( n.id == 3 ){
    c = g.getNeighbors(n);
    System.out.println(C); C.add(n); }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `UndirectedSparseMultigraph.getNeighbors(V vertex)`  to get the `Vertices` this method returns an unmodifiable collection

```java
  public Collection<V> getNeighbors(V vertex) {
  ...
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(neighbors);
  }
```

As do

```java
  public Collection<V> getVertices()
  {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(vertex_maps.keySet());
  }
```

and

```java
  public Collection<E> getEdges()
  {
    Collection<E> edges = new ArrayList<E>(directed_edges.keySet());
    edges.addAll(undirected_edges.keySet());
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(edges);
  }
```

Based on your comments it appers that you are trying to add a node `n` to the collection of its `neighbors`.  If this is the case have your tried replacing

`( C.add(n)))`

with

`g.addEdge(new MyLink(), n, n);`

to add a self intersection.

Comment: This is almost certainly the reason.  To give some context, the collections were made to be unmodifiable because removing a vertex or edge, and adding an edge, requires some internal bookkeeping to keep the data structures in a good state.  (Adding a vertex could be done via add() on the collection but for reasons of consistency it's also handled via a separate method, i.e., addVertex()).

Comment: UndirectedSparseMultigraph<MyNode, MyLink> g = getgraph1();
   
   Collection<MyNode> C = null ;
  for(MyNode n:g.getVertices()){
    if(n.id==3){
     C = g.getNeighbors(n);
     System.out.println(C);
     
     
     
      C.add(n);
     }
     
     //System.out.println("La collection est "  +C); 
     }}

Comment: Thanks . I'd like to construct a modifiable collection of node that is possible to add or delete some of its objects. this is my purpose. (why using g.adding()!! this node is a member of g)

Comment: @Delel I'm afraid that I don't really understand what you are trying to do.  Can I suggest that you accept this answer (as it explains why your code resulted in an `Exception`) and then ask a new question the comments section is not the best place to continue.