# Removing RDF graph dead-ends using Jung

Tags: java, rdf, jung

I am trying to implement a method that removes dead-ends from an RDF graph

```
Iterator<String> iter = rdfGraph.getVertices().iterator();  
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String x = iter.next();
        if(rdfGraph.outDegree(x)==0){

            iter.remove();
        }

    }
```

Whenever i run this i get a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. How can I fix my code.

Comment: What library are you using for your graph? What does "getVertices/outDegree" refer to?

Comment: jena apache and jung

get vertices returns a Collevction view of all vertices in the graph.

out degree returns the number of edges connecting from the vertex to any other vertex

Comment: if i do that i get a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. that's why I introduced the iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator's [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) method is optional.   The javadoc mentions that when it's not supported, it will throw an **UnsupportedOperationException**:

> #### Throws:
>
> UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not
>   supported by this iterator

Based on the discussion in [adding a node to a collection using JUNG2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069243/adding-a-node-to-a-collection-using-jung2), I'd assume that **getVertices()** returns a an unmodifiable collection, in which case the iterator wouldn't support **remove()**.  Note that the javadoc for **getVertices()** says that the method returns a *view* of the vertices.  It doesn't say that adding or removing from the collection adds or removes vertices from the graph, or that adding or removing vertices from the collection is even possible.

> **getVertices** `Collection<V> getVertices()`
>
> Returns a view of all vertices in this graph. In general, this obeys the Collection contract, and therefore makes no guarantees about
>   the ordering of the vertices within the set.

Instead of **iter.remove()**, it probably makes more sense to use **rdfGraph.removeVertex(x)**.

But, based on your comment

> *I used rdfGraph.removeVertex(x) initially but i got a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. any idea on how I could bypass this without using an iterator?*

It sounds like you either need to go through the vertices and create a new collection of which ones you want to remove, and then remove them after you're done iterating through the vertices.  Alternatively, you could create a new collection of *all* the vertices and then remove them as you go through.  E.g.,

```
new ArrayList<>(rdfGraph.getVertices()).stream()
  .filter(v -> rdfGraph.outDegree(x) == 0)
  .forEach(rdfGraph::removeVertex);
```

The use of ArrayList isn't important there;  you just need some new collection that's not connected to the original graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used rdfGraph.removeVertex(x) initially but i got a  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. any idea on how I could bypass this without using an iterator?

Comment: @user1839226 You didn't mention that in your question.  If you had, I would not have suggested this work around in the answer.  It sounds like you're getting an iterator that doesn't support remove, but a collection that is too closely tied to the graph to modify during iteration.  It sounds like you'll either need to collect the vertices you want to remove and remove them separately afterward, or copy the collection of vertices. That could be as simple as, e.g., `new ArrayList<>(rdfGraph.getVertices()).forEach(rdfGraph::removeVertex);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. why was it necessary to use an arraylist though?

Comment: @user1839226 It didn't need to be an ArrayList;  any Collection would have been fine.